# error in phpmailer while sending bulk mail

Tags: php, phpmailer

trying to send more than 2000 mails by fetching email id from Database, actually 240 mails sent successfully , after that i got some error like this

**code**

```
$mail->addAttachment('images/attach.gif');
$mysql = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('db_name', $mysql);
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, email_id FROM email WHERE status = '0'", $mysql);
$body = file_get_contents('contents.php');
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {

    $mail->AltBody = 'alt body text here';
    $mail->msgHTML($body);
    $mail->addAddress($row1['email_id'], $row1['first_name']);

    if (!$mail->send()) 
    {
        echo "Mailer Error (" . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $row1["email_id"]) . ') ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br />';
        break; //Abandon sending
    } else 
    {
        echo "Message sent to :" . $row1['first_name'] . ' (' . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $row1['email_id']) . ')<br />';
    }
    // Clear all addresses and attachments for next loop
    $mail->clearAddresses();
    $mail->clearAttachments();
}
```

after 240+ mail sent i got this kind if errors , i m new to phpmailer please tell me what is the problem and how to fix this problem, the bug

**error**

```
    Mailer Error (***email***) The following From address failed: test@trbu.in : MAIL FROM command failed,503,sender already given 
    Mailer Error (***email***) The following From address failed: test@trbu.in : MAIL FROM command failed,503,sender already given 
    Mailer Error (***email***) SMTP Error: data not accepted.
    Mailer Error (***email***) The following From address failed: test@trbu.in : MAIL FROM command failed,503,sender already given  
    Mailer Error (***email***) The following From address failed: test@trbu.in : MAIL FROM command failed,503,sender already given 
...
...
...
```

Comment: I removed the plain text emails appearing in your error message. Your customers might not want their address displayed here... The error seems to come from the part where you set your `FROM` param, but it doesn't seem to be in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using [latest PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). `msgHTML()` also sets `AltBody`, so if you want a custom `AltBody`, set it after the call to `msgHTML`.

The `MAIL FROM` errors suggest you may not be completing a previous message, which could be due to misformatted content or a message count limit during a single session. If you enable debugging with `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`, you'll be able to see more of the conversation.

Try setting `$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = false;` to make it send each message separately (which is slower but more reliable), as this may be because you are trying to send more messages in a single connection than your host allows. You could make your send loop close and reopen the SMTP connection every 200 messages to avoid this issue.